# Is a temporary facebook login to share a link possible?

Tags: javascript, facebook, ipad, sharing

An ipad at a kiosk is going to house an info page that the client wants visitors to be able to share on their facebook.

We planned to have a modal pop open that lets the user sign in a share, but we have no way of guaranteeing the user will sign out.

Is there any way to do a [sign-in --> Share --> sign-out], without needing the user to click sign-out? Even if they end up not sharing, we need it to sign out once they close the share modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
FB.logout(function(){
    /* logout callback */
});
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Comment: It says I need a "valid access token" to call this.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8430474/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token

Comment: This works if the logged-in user has my FB application installed, otherwise it throws an error.

Comment: So, if I want to do this then I will need to authenticate a user to my app with FB.login(). I think this is good enough to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: No, if the user doesn't grant permissions to my app, then I cant call FB.logout() even if I call FB.getLoginStatus()

Comment: Actually this isnt going to work. If a user logs in with FB.login() but doesnt accept the app, then I cant logout the user with FB.logout()

Comment: so, it's dependent on the user accepting your app. in other words, you'll only be able to logout users that allow you to log them out - which is a good thing. looks like you have to go back to the drawing board. i can't continue helping you unless you provide a detailed scenario/context.

Comment: Its nothing more then a public pc at a trade show, where a person can come up, fill out a form then have the option to share it on their facebook. We need a auto sign out because there may be a line of people waiting to use the machine and we dont want to risk a persons privacy. This doesn't appear possible, so I will tell them we cant do it.